# How do I change the line style to dash in a scattermapbox plot?

Tags: python, plotly

I’m trying to change the line style of 'Natural Trails' to a dash in a scattermapbox. However, there is no option to do so according to the documentation as `line` only accepts a `dict` of with properties of `width` and `color`. Is there a work around to this?

Currently plots a solid line: _____________

Trying to plot a dashed line: - - - - - - - - - - - -

> ValueError: Invalid property specified for object of type plotly.graph_objs.scattermapbox.Line: 'dash'

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(
    data=[
        go.Scattermapbox(
            name='Railroad',
            hoverinfo='name',
            lat=fcrl_lats,
            lon=fcrl_lons,
            mode="lines",
            line=dict(width=2, color="#ff4931")
        ),
        go.Scattermapbox(
            name='Bike Lanes',
            hoverinfo='name',
            lat=hcbl_lats,
            lon=hcbl_lons,
            mode="lines",
            line=dict(width=2, color="#006699")
        ),
        go.Scattermapbox(
            name='Natural Trails',
            hoverinfo='name',
            lat=nat_lats,
            lon=nat_lons,
            mode="lines",
            line=dict(dash='dash', width=1, color="#38ad74")
        )
    ]
)
fig.update_layout(
    showlegend=True,
    legend=mapLegend,
    margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0},
    mapbox=go.layout.Mapbox(
        style="carto-positron", 
        zoom=12, 
        center_lat = 40.55,
        center_lon = -105.08,
    )
)
fig.show()
```